# For loop problem to for next elements in a list

Tags: python, loops

In python, if I have a list

```
lst=["Word", "Bar", "List", "Warrior", "When", "Apple", "Car"]
```

and I want to determine for each element if the next element is a word that begins with `W`, how could I write my for loop?

Comment: It is a common practice to include in your question, examples of things you have tried, errors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=["Word", "Bar", "List", "Warrior", "When", "Apple", "Car"]
for i in range(len(lst) -1):
  if lst[i + 1][0] == "W":
    print(i)
```